# Getting global Javascript variable in another Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVariable = "something";
</script>
```

After this js global variable declaration I have another javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScriptFile.js"></script>
```

In this file I need to use the value of my global `myVariable` variable. I know that I can do it by setting this value in some HTML, then using DOM or jQuery or something else get this value in the file, but I want to avoid creating those kind of hidden fields in my HTML. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You can set the variable on the `window` object instead from any external file: `window.myVariable = "something";`, then you just need to make sure it gets set before you use it in `myScriptFile.js`

Comment: @RGraham It's already added to the window object. No need to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it [global](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable/);

script1.js

```
 var foobar = "O HAI";
```

script2.js

```
  alert(foobar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything that you will put in `window` in any place (even in functions) will be visible in global scope. So

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.myVariable = "something";
</script>
```

And `myVariable` will be visible anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I use global variables with

```
jQuery.data(document.body, "varAgrup", { var1: value1, var2: value2 });
```

I get var value with

```
jQuery.data(document.body, "varAgrup").var1;
```

Comment: the best solution I would say :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global variable in the myScriptFile.js file if it was defined before the script which will use it on the same page.